# Strapi Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toISOString') while trying to delete dateTime picker

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, digital-ocean, strapi

I have a problem with the datetime picker. In my Strapi dashboard, I have a field where users can specify a date and time. When I try to remove the date and time completely and make the input field empty, it throws the following error in the console. What could be causing this error? I am using a PostgreSQL database, and the project is deployed on DigitalOcean.

[image]

[image]